# Symfony3 form overrides default property set in Entity

Tags: forms, entity, symfony

I just recently noticed that my code is not working anymore and I am not really sure if I do something wrong or there's a bug in Symfony3.

So I got a entity `User` which have property `isActive` set in a constructor as `isActive = 1`

When I wire the entity with the UserType, suddenly my default value of `isActive` property is not `1` but `NULL`,

so here's how it looks like:

```
    $user = new User();
    var_dump($user->getIsActive()); // gives 1
    $form = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user);
    var_dump($user->getIsActive()); // gives 1
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    var_dump($user->getIsActive()); // gives NULL
```

Here's how `UserType` looks like:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $option)
{
    $this->name($builder);
    $this->isActive($builder);
}
```

And `isActive` trait

```
trait IsActiveField
{
    public function isActive(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options = [])
    {
        $defaultOptions = [
           'label' => 'word.is_active',
           'choices' => ['word.no' => 0, 'word.yes' => 1],
        ];

        $options = array_merge($defaultOptions, $options);
        return $builder->add('isActive', ChoiceType::class, $options);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems strange that your user's variable is named `$user`, but the second argument of the `createForm` method is a `$program` variable:

```
$user = new User();
$form = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $program);
```

Comment: Hey laroslav, thanks for pointing this out, however it was my bad copy-pasting. Problem still occurs. I did not mention this but it happens to me when I post via ajax, using FOSRestBundle

Comment: And what data do you send in this request?